# Automatically subtracting from value after the player turn

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to get the function `CvPRandomSpeler` to automatically subtract from the value of `aantal_munten`by 2 when it is the `Computer`turn and the value is 2 or 5. Or by 1 when the value is 1 to 7 (except for 2,5) and it is the `Computer` turn.

After the subtraction it is supposed to automatically go back to `Speler`.

I only copied te relavant code so there is a big part missing.

Thanks!

```
import tkinter
import random
from time import sleep

def CvPRandomSpeler():
    '''
    Deze functie laat binnen het speler tegen computer optie de computer en speler wisselen nadat er een munt gepakt is.
    Daarnaast wordt er een update aangevraagd voor het label beurt_speler per wisseling van speler/computer.
    '''
    global speler_computer
    global aantal_munten
    if speler_computer == 'Speler':
        speler_computer = 'Computer'
        aantal_munten in [2,5]
        CvPMunt2()
    elif speler_computer == 'Speler':
        speler_computer = 'Computer'
        aantal_munten in [1,3,4,6,7]
        CvPMunt1()
    else:
        speler_computer = 'Speler'
    welke_beurt.config(text= speler_computer + ' is aan de beurt!')
    sleep(.5)
    return speler_computer

def CvPMunt1():
    '''
    Deze funtie wordt aangeroepen binnen de speler tegen computer optie als een speler de knop 1 munt indrukt.
    De functie trekt 2 van het totaal aantal munten af wat over is, en geeft een update aan het label wat het totaal aantal munten bijhoudt.
    '''
    global aantal_munten
    eenMunt = 1
    aantal_munten -= eenMunt
    munten.configure(text='Er zijn nog ' + (str(aantal_munten)) + ' aantal munten over, hoeveel pak je er?')
    if aantal_munten <= 0:
        CvPtoonEindscherm()
    else:
        # change player
        CvPRandomSpeler()

def CvPMunt2():
    '''
    Deze funtie wordt aangeroepen binnen de speler tegen speler optie als een computer de knop 2 munten indrukt.
    De functie trekt 2 van het totaal aantal munten af wat over is, en geeft een update aan het label wat het totaal aantal munten bijhoudt.
    '''
    global aantal_munten
    tweeMunt = 2
    if aantal_munten >= 2:
        aantal_munten -= tweeMunt
        munten.configure(text='Er zijn nog ' + (str(aantal_munten)) + ' aantal munten over, hoeveel pak je er?')
        CvPRandomSpeler()
    elif aantal_munten == 1:
        munten.configure(text='Er is nog ' + (str(aantal_munten)) + ' munt, pak één munt!')
    elif aantal_munten <= 0:
        CvPtoonEindscherm()

nim_spel = tkinter.Tk()#maakt Tkinter venster aan

global aantal_munten #zet een global aantal_munten op welke gebruikt wordt in de functies en labels
aantal_munten = 7

global speler_computer #zet een global voor de speler/computer op welke gebruikt wordt in de functies en labels
speler_computer = random.choice(['Speler', 'Computer']) #zorgt ervoor dat er een willekeurige speler/computer start

computerscherm = tkinter.Frame(master=nim_spel) #maakt het speler tegen computer scherm, geeft een label met het overige aantal munten en of de speler aan de beurt is, ook twee knoppen die elk één of twee munten van de overige munten af halen
computerscherm.pack()
welke_beurt = tkinter.Label(computerscherm, text= (speler_computer) + ' is aan de beurt')
welke_beurt.pack()
munten = tkinter.Label(computerscherm, text='Er zijn nog ' + str(aantal_munten) + ' aantal munten over')
munten.pack()
CvP_pak_1_munt = tkinter.Button(computerscherm, text='1 munt', fg = 'blue', command=CvPMunt1)
CvP_pak_1_munt.pack(side = 'left')
CvP_pak_2_munt = tkinter.Button(computerscherm, text='2 munten', fg = 'blue', command=CvPMunt2)
CvP_pak_2_munt.pack(side = 'right')


toonStartscherm()
nim_spel.mainloop()
```

Comment: Shorten the amount of code you have presented. Present the absolute relevant part. You wont receive much help otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The lines `aantal_munten in [2,5]` and `aantal_munten in [1,3,4,6,7]` do nothing, here: they evalute to True or False but the code does nothing with the result. If you want them to do something with these statements, you need to use them in an if statement or something similar.